# IE adding background color on hover

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background, padding

IE 10, 9, 8 and 7 for some reason adds a stupid background to my navigation links when you click on them, when you hover on them everything happens the way it should, but then when you click it this stupid white background color comes up behind it, like it gets affected by my padding, but if I remove my padding you could imagine my navbar screwing up.

```
#navbar {
width:1000px;
height:30px;
margin-top:-35px;
position:relative;
border-radius:3px;
-webkit-border-radius:3px;
-moz-border-radius:3px;
behavior:url(../CSSPie/PIE.htc);
}

#navbar ul {
list-style:none;
}

#navbar li, a {
display:inline;
font-family:Calibri, "Calibri Light", Cambria, "Cambria Math";
text-decoration:none;
color:#CCC;
padding:5px 10px 0px 0px;
border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
behavior:url(../CSSPie/PIE.htc);
}

#navbar a:hover {
color:#FFF;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826163/ie-not-respecting-hover-on-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the default styles for the tag `anchor`.

```
a:link { }
a:visited { }
a:hover { }
a:active { }
```

Probably IE has established some defaults that are affecting to your styles, so you can try to override them in order to make it look nice with your styles.

You are saying that they break when you click on them, probably you have to override `active` or `visited` styles. Something like:

```
a:visited { background: none; }
a:active { background: none; }
```

or:

```
a:visited { background-color: transparent; }
a:active { background-color: transparent; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! By setting background:none; on a:hover it worked.